# Can I use column names as data

Tags: impala

I have to check the data in each column in 7000 tables.
So I want to insert into Temp_Table has Columns ( Table_name, Column_name, Data)

### eg.
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;

| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DATA_A1 | DATA_B1 | DATA_C1 |
| DATA_A2 | DATA_B2 | DATA_C2 |

I want to insert into Temp_table
eg.

| TABLE_NM | COL_NM | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE_A | COL_A | DATA_A1 |
| TABLE_A | COL_A | DATA_A2 |
| TABLE_A | COL_B | DATA_B1 |
| TABLE_A | COL_B | DATA_B2 |
| TABLE_A | COL_C | DATA_C1 |
| TABLE_A | COL_C | DATA_C2 |

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using union all from metadata.

```
select 'TABLE_A' TABLE_NM, 'COL_A' COL_NM, COL_A DATA from table_a
union all
select 'TABLE_A' TABLE_NM, 'COL_B' COL_NM, COL_B DATA from table_a 
union all
select 'TABLE_A' TABLE_NM, 'COL_C' COL_NM, COL_C DATA from table_a
...
```

Put the list of table and columns in XL and then create a formula to create the whole query. But list of tables and columns - you need to get from metadata.